# Dynamic Excel graph

Tags: vba, excel

At the moment, I have created four different graphs that appear only if they are called in my drop-down box on cell D5. However, I am trying to create a single dynamic graph that populates its data depending on what is in cell D5.

Is this possible?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("D5")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        If Range("D5") = "Tremont" Then
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Tremont").Visible = True
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SaybrookPointe").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("21Fitzsimons").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Mezzo").Visible = False

        ElseIf Range("D5") = "Saybrook Pointe" Then
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Tremont").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SaybrookPointe").Visible = True
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("21Fitzsimons").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Mezzo").Visible = False

        ElseIf Range("D5") = "21 Fitzsimons" Then
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Tremont").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SaybrookPointe").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("21Fitzsimons").Visible = True
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Mezzo").Visible = False

        ElseIf Range("D5") = "Mezzo" Then
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Tremont").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("SaybrookPointe").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("21Fitzsimons").Visible = False
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Mezzo").Visible = True

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible. Instead of choosing which chart to appear, you can edit the chart elements based on your selection of d5

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and figure out how to add data to the graphs as D5 is changed. I like the idea of only having 1 graph as compared to 4. I'll upvote you once my rep gets high enough.

Comment: Hey if you can show me what chart elements you have and also the type of chart, i can help you with complete code which will use only 1 graph instead of switching between 4

Comment: Basically I have 4 sets of properties that have rent data going horizontally, with the corresponding month of the rent data going horizontally at the top. The properties are listed going down vertically. I can't copy and paste due to size restrictions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("D5")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

If Range("D5") = "Tremont" Then
    Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(X_axis_values)
    Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Tremont"
    Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).Values  = Range(Y_axis_values)


'If a bar graph,
with Selection.Format.Fill
.Visible = msoTrue
.ForeColor.RGB= RGB(0,0,0)
.Transparency = 0
.Solid
End With          

 ElseIf Range("D5") = "Saybrook Pointe" Then
     Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(X_axis_values)
     Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Saybrook Pointe"
     Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).Values  = Range(Y_axis_values)

'If a bar graph,
with Selection.Format.Fill
.Visible = msoTrue
.ForeColor.RGB= RGB(0,0,0)
.Transparency = 0
.Solid
End With          

        ElseIf Range("D5") = "21 Fitzsimons" Then
            'Similarly like above cases, define the X-axis,the series name and the values.
        ElseIf Range("D5") = "Mezzo" Then
            'Similarly like above cases, define the X-axis,the series name and the values.
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Following these links would give you more information on how to work more on charts

[Intoduction to charts](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/3/1/the-vba-coding-guide-for-excel-charts-graph?rq=charts)

[Chart series elements](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_class_module_to_manipulate_a_chart_series/)

Comment: Thank you so much Kanike! I did start another question for this very issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358216/single-dynamic-graph-code), which I may just take down thanks to your help.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with this. But you can make it simpler and avoid hardcoding the names, and you can save some inc as well:

```
Dim ch As ChartObject
For Each ch in ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    ch.Visible = ch.Name = Range("D5").Value
Next
```

But, well, you need to remove the spaces from the names in the `D5` list, letting them be *exactly* equal to the charts' names.

Comment: This is certainly helpful. I will use that code until I can figure out a way to create a single graph that has data changing when I update cell D5. I'd upvote you if I could :/

Comment: @Tollbooth the ChartObject has methods to manipulate the Data Series it handles. But that is a completely another issue :)