# Single Dynamic Graph Code

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, I have 4 sets of properties that have rent data going horizontally, with the corresponding month of the rent data going horizontally at the top. The properties are listed going down vertically.

```
           June,'15  July,'15
Set 1                   
prop 1    $2,588.00     $2,588.00
prop 2    $1,835.00     $1,829.00   

Set 2                       
prop 3    $2,647.00     $2,707.00
prop 4    $2,501.00     $2,526.00
```

I want to create a VBA code with for a single graph that chooses the data from either property Set 1 or Set 2 to add to the graph. This is dependent on another cell (drop-down) changing in Excel:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("D5")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        'This is where I would place the graph code
    End If

End Sub
```

What would be the code to achieve such a task - building a dynamically changing graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("D5")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

If Range("D5") = "Tremont" Then
    Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(X_axis_values)
    Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Tremont"
    Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).Values  = Range(Y_axis_values)


'If a bar graph,
with Selection.Format.Fill
.Visible = msoTrue
.ForeColor.RGB= RGB(0,0,0)
.Transparency = 0
.Solid
End With          

 ElseIf Range("D5") = "Saybrook Pointe" Then
     Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(X_axis_values)
     Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Saybrook Pointe"
     Activesheet.Chartobjects("Single_Dynamic_Chart").FullSeriesCollection(1).Values  = Range(Y_axis_values)

'If a bar graph,
with Selection.Format.Fill
.Visible = msoTrue
.ForeColor.RGB= RGB(0,0,0)
.Transparency = 0
.Solid
End With   



        ElseIf Range("D5") = "21 Fitzsimons" Then
            'Similarly like above cases, define the X-axis,the series name and the values.
        ElseIf Range("D5") = "Mezzo" Then
            'Similarly like above cases, define the X-axis,the series name and the values.
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```